# Write something to text field when any item from combobox is selected

Tags: java, string, swing, jcombobox, string-comparison

I want to write something to a text field when I select any item from combo box.  But I couldn't do this.

Java code:

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            if(comboBox.getSelectedItem()=="apple") {
                tfbf.setText("apple selected");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well you compare objects equality with `equals`..  `==` just compares reference if they pointing to the same object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you don't provide any valid example . You compare object observational equality with `equals(..)` not with `==`.

```
"apple".equals(comboBox.getSelectedItem())
```

Read more [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

> `==` tests for reference equality.
>
> `.equals()` tests for value equality.

Comment: thanks so much. I ve solved with this code

Comment: Nitpick "apple".equals(comboBox.getSelectedItem()) would avoid possible NullPointerException ... +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer i appreciate yoda style but for this example i think is not necessary, by the way it's not 5 am there?

Comment: @nachokk Good practice makes perfect and yes...

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok i edited

Answer (score 3):

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0)
    {
        if(comboBox.getSelectedItem()=="apple")
        {
              tfbf.setText("apple selected");
        }
    }
});
```

Is probably better written as:

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0)
    {
        tfbf.setText(comboBox.getSelectedItem() + " selected");
    }
});
```

Comment: @assylias  I do not understand your comment.  Are you referring to me or the OP?  I added the Swing tag of course.  I intimated Swing from the use of `ItemListener`.  Does Java-FX also use the `ItemListener`?

Comment: for some reason I thought it was a JavaFX ComboBox but I was mistaken! In JavaFX it would be something like: `comboBox.addChangeListener(...)`

Comment: @assylias Aah..  I must admit I am not entirely sure it is Swing.  It could be pure AWT for all I know.  OP - For better help sooner, post an **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).**

Comment: Nice! Did you write that? It looks like MVCE == summarize(SSCCE)!

Comment: @assylias  Thanks! It is based on [what I wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215383/155831) (community WIKI answer).

Comment: @assylias  I actually just noticed it has become MCVT on that thread!  ;)

Comment: so now it will be `For better help sooner post a MCVT` ?

Comment: @nachokk No.. for the moment I'm sticking with what it is seen at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (I suspect the Wiki change will not be adopted).